# Having issue with the FormField Component

Tags: reactjs

I am a complete newbie in React JS. I am currently working on a DALL-E Clone website.
The issue I am currently facing is as follows:

I have a page called CreatePost.jsx where I am calling a custom React component called FormField.

Here is the code for CreatePost.jsx:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'

import {preview} from '../assets';
import {getRandomPrompt} from '../utils';
import { FormField, Loader } from '../components';

const CreatePost = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    name:'',
    prompt: '',
    photo: ''
  })

  const [generatingImg, setGeneratingImg] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = () => {

  }

  const handleChange = (e) => {

  }

  const handleSupriseMe = () => {

  }

  return (
    <section className="max-w-7xl mx-auto">
      <div>
        <h1 className='font-extrabold text-[#222328] text-[32px]'>
          Create
        </h1>
        <p className="mt-2 text-[#666e75] text-[16px] max-w[500px]">
          Create imaginative and visually stunning through DALL-E AI and share them with the community
        </p>
      </div>

      <form className="mt-16 max-w-3xl" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-5">
          <FormField 
            LabelName="Your Name"
            type="text"
            name="name"
            placeholder="John Doe"
            value={form.name}
            handleChange={handleChange}
            form={form}
            generatingImg={generatingImg}
          />
          <FormField 
            LabelName="Prompt"
            type="text"
            name="prompt"
            placeholder="An armchair in the shape of an avocado"
            value={form.prompt}
            handleChange={handleChange}
            isSupriseMe
            handleSupriseMe = {handleSupriseMe}
            form={form}
            generatingImg={generatingImg}
          />
        </div>
      </form>
    </section>
  )
}

export default CreatePost
```

Here is the code for FormField.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { preview } from '../assets';

const FormField = ({LabelName, type, name, placeholder, value, 
  handleChange, isSupriseMe, handleSupriseMe, form, generatingImg}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex items-center gap-2 mb-2">
        <label
          htmlFor={name}
          className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-900"
        > 
        {LabelName}
        </label>
        {isSupriseMe && (
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={handleSupriseMe}
            className="font-semibold text-xs bg-[#ececf1] py-1 px-2 rounded-[5px] text-black"
          >
            Surprise Me!
          </button>
        )}
      </div>
      <input 
        type={type}
        id={name}
        name={name}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        required
        className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 
        text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-[#6469ff] 
        focus: border-[#4649ff] outline-none block w-full p-3"
      />

      <div className="relative bg-gray-50 borderr border-gray-300 
      text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 
      focus:border-blue-500 w-64 p-3 h-644 flex justify-center items-center">
        {form.photo ? (
          <img 
          src={form.photo} 
          alt={form.prompt}
          className="w-full h-full object-contain" 
          />
        ) : (
          <img 
            src={preview}
            alt={preview}
            className="w-9/12 h-9/12 object-contain opacity-40"
          />
        )}
        {generatingImg && (
          <div className='absolute inset-0 z-0 flex justify-center 
          items-center bg-[rgba(0,0,0,0.5)] rounded-lg'>
            
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


FormField.propTypes = {
  LabelName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  type: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  handleChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isSupriseMe: PropTypes.bool,
  handleSupriseMe: PropTypes.func,
  form: PropTypes.shape({
    photo: PropTypes.string,
    prompt: PropTypes.string,
  }).isRequired,
  generatingImg: PropTypes.bool
};

export default FormField
```

Now the issue I am facing is that when I run the above scripts, I get a blank page with a white screen.

I am not sure what I should change or add in the code.

I was expecting something like this:

[image]

When I comment out the following block of code in FormField.jsx:

```
{form.photo ? (
          <img 
          src={form.photo} 
          alt={form.prompt}
          className="w-full h-full object-contain" 
          />
        ) : (
          <img 
            src={preview}
            alt={preview}
            className="w-9/12 h-9/12 object-contain opacity-40"
          />
        )}
        {generatingImg && (
          <div className='absolute inset-0 z-0 flex justify-center 
          items-center bg-[rgba(0,0,0,0.5)] rounded-lg'>
            
          </div>
        )}
```

[image]

I believe there is some issue in the above lines code.